# Reading dbf file from s3 throwing error - 'int' object has no attribute 'isalpha'

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3, dbf

I am developing a python aws lambda function for migrating dbf files into mysql after reading it from s3. Lambda function get triggered after every dbf file upload. Here is my code,

```
 import boto3
 import io 
 from dbfread import DBF 
 s3 = boto3.client('s3')
 obj = s3.get_object(Bucket='XXXXXX', Key='test.dbf')
 f   = io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read())
 for line in f.readlines():    
     for r in DBF(line,encoding='utf-8'):
         print(r)
```

[image]

but when I am executing the script I'm getting the below error.

```
File "E:\Projects\dbf_mysql_migration\dbfread\dbf.py", line 108, in __init__
    self.filename = ifind(filename)
  File "E:\Projects\dbf_mysql_migration\dbfread\ifiles.py", line 55, in ifind
    files = iglob(pat)
  File "E:\Projects\dbf_mysql_migration\dbfread\ifiles.py", line 44, in iglob
    return glob.glob(ipat(pat))
  File "E:\Projects\dbf_mysql_migration\dbfread\ifiles.py", line 24, in ipat
    if c.isalpha:
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isalpha'
```

Can you please help me? Is there any better way to read dbf files as streams from s3 .

Comment: I am also facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I solved following the next steps:

1. Create linux ec2 instance
2. Mount S3 bucket as a filesystem in the linux ec2 instance
3. Write a Python function reading the files with the sentence dbf_data = DBF(file, encoding='iso-8859-1')

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).